# Setting UIButton Image With Ternary Operator

Tags: ios, swift

I have a password `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UITextField` to enter the password. I want to have a button where the user can change the isSecureTextEntry property.

### My Code

```
private lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let view = UIButton()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle), for: .touchUpInside)
    return view
}()

@objc func toggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected == false ? button.setImage(secureImage, for: .normal) : button.setImage(unSecureImage, for: .selected)
}
```

### Set Up Cell

```
    self.toggle(button)
```

However, my button image is not changing.

Comment: Your button is being tapped, not selected, so `isSelected` is probably not the right field.

Comment: If you want to change image while user tapping , Needed field is highlighted not to selected

Comment: Better to set the image for normal and select at the time of button creation and change the only button state on toggle action.

Comment: How about `textField.isSecureTextEntry = !textField.isSecureTextEntry` rather than a terinary operator. You can also do `sender.isSelected = !textField.isSecureTextEntry`. Probably have to dispatchqueue to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
sender.isSelected == false ? button.setImage(secureImage, for: .normal) : button.setImage(unSecureImage, for: .selected)
```

You're setting for normal state on one side and for selected state on the other.

Try this:

```
button.setImage((sender.isSelected ? unSecureImage : secureImage), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this,

- Setting the image for normal and selected state
- On tapping the button changing the isSelected state of the button

  ```
  private lazy var button: UIButton = {
     let view = UIButton()
     view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     view.setImage(secureImage, for: .normal)
     view.setImage(unSecureImage, for: .selected)
     view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    return view
  }()

  @objc func toggleAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
  }
  ```